# How to make a global code change

Tags: command-line

I'm re-using a lot of code from one site to a new one. I need to change two link addresses throughout, e.g. /abc/ to /cba/ and abc.com to abc.us. I can log into the server and use 'terminal' software or edit it locally with a php editor. The editor I have does not have that capability. I have thousands of lines of code and can't find all the cases where the change is needed.

There must be a simple solution. I just don't know where to find it.

Comment: Does `sed 's/abc.com/abc.us/g' <oldfile >newfile` help?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `grep` to find the files that contain `abc.com`.
And then you could use `sed` to replace `abc.com` with `abc.us`.
You just need to be careful to avoid false positives.
I would first add all site files to a Git repository,
then perform the replacements,
check the replacements with `git diff`,
so that if something went wrong, I could easily roll back.

```bsh
cd path/to/site
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'Add files'
grep -rlFwZ abc.com . | xargs -0 sed -i 's/\<abc\.com\>/abc.us/g'
git diff
```

Explanation of the flags of `grep`:

- `-r` search recursively in all sub-directories
- `-l` print filenames that matched instead of the matches
- `-F` treat the pattern as a literal string, not as a regular expression (keep the `.` a dot, not "any character")
- `-w` match whole words (so that "foo abc.com bar" matches, while "fooabc.com bar" or "foo abc.combar" doesn't)

In the pattern of `sed` the `\<` and `\>` serve the same logic as the `-w` of the `grep`, and the `.` is escaped to serve the same logic as the `-F` of the `grep`.

Answer (score 2):

There is an app for exactly that work flow in the default Ubuntu repositories called Geany. Geany is so lightweight that it can batch edit 50 web files at the same time. Because Geany is a GUI program it's transparently easy to use, and it has the advantage over using the terminal that you can see what you are doing because each file is open in a separate tab. Geany's *Replace* feature supports regular expressions which is useful for editing markup tags. When I'm done editing the multiple files, I typically open all 50 of them together in a web browser to check my work.

To install Geany in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install geany
```

Answer (score 1):

These two commands should be helpful:

```
grep -RlZE abc.com /path/to/folders | xargs -0 sed -i 's/abc.com/abc.us/g'

grep -RlZE \/abc\/ /path/to/folders | xargs -0 sed -i 's_/abc/_/cba/_g'
```

More information:

- `grep -RlZE abc.com /path/to/folders`: looks for files tha contain the texts your trying to change, and returns the file path. This will be given to the `sed` command.
- `-R`: Search recursively through the files
- `-l`: Return file path for matches only
- `-E`: grep extended regex switch
- `-Z`: Used to handle files with odd string characters

To create backups, assuming space isn't an issue, run the commands like so to create backups incase someting goes wrong:

```
grep -RlZE abc.com /path/to/folders | xargs -0 sed -i.bak 's/abc.com/abc.us/g'

grep -RlZE \/abc\/ /path/to/folders | xargs -0 sed -i.bak 's_/abc/_/cba/_g'
```

Comment: Ah yes totally forgot that, @DavidFoerster. Thanks for HUD!

Comment: Yes i considered that but also considered the fact that space could be an issue too! But will mention that in the answer